# Joomla 2.5 Login not working after editing php.ini file

Tags: file-upload, php, joomla2.5

- I have created a php.ini file under public_html/

  ```
  containing the following lines
  post_max_size = 2048M
  upload_max_filesize = 2048M
  max_execution_time= 6000000
  file_uploads = On
  ```

  **after editing php.ini file upload working perfectly but 
  i am not able login or logout from joomla**

  **If php.ini file is removed login/logout working perfectly 
  But i cant upload file larger than 10 MB**

  i am using BlueHost as Hosting and Joomla 2.5

  Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved the issue was SWF file Resetting the Session ID.